# Need help setting up Karma with Webpack - files not getting loaded

Tags: webpack, karma-jasmine

Webpack 1.3.1
Babel 5.8.35
Barma 1.1.2

First time setting this up, some of my files are not getting loaded, looks like they got errors of some sort in them but I am unable to figure out what exactly as I get no error messages in the output.
I am not sure I am doing it right honestly, here's my Karma config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('../tools/webpack.config.babel');
const RewirePlugin = require("rewire-webpack");
const path = require('path');
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const RELEASE = !!argv.release;
const DEBUG = !!argv.debug;
const BROWSERS = argv.browsers;

module.exports = function(config) {
    function getReporters() {
        return ['junit', 'progress'];
    }

    function getBrowsers() {
        let browsers = ['PhantomJS'];
        if (BROWSERS) {
            return BROWSERS.split(',');
        }
        if (RELEASE) {
            browsers = ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'IE'];
        } else if (DEBUG) {
            browsers = ['Chrome'];
        }
        return browsers;
    }

    function getFiles() {
        let files = [
            'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'node_modules/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui.js',
            'test/tests.jsx'
        ];
        return files;
    }

    function getPreprocessors() {
        return {
            'test/tests.jsx': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
            'src/**/*(js|jsx)': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        };
    }
    function configureWebpackConfig() {
        webpackConfig.plugins = [];
        webpackConfig.plugins.push(new RewirePlugin());
        webpackConfig.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
        return webpackConfig;
    }
    config.set({

        basePath: path.join(__dirname, '../'),

        files: getFiles(),

        singleRun: false,

        preprocessors: getPreprocessors(),

        webpack: configureWebpackConfig(),

        webpackServer: {
            stats: {
                colors: true
            }
        },

        webpackMiddleware: {
            // webpack-dev-middleware configuration
            // i. e.
            noInfo: true
        },

        browserNoActivityTimeout: 1000000,

        // coverage reporter generates the coverage
        reporters: ['junit', 'progress'],

        autoWatch: false,

        frameworks: [
            'jasmine',
            'jasmine-matchers'
        ],

        browsers: getBrowsers(),

        plugins: [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher-nonet',
            'karma-ie-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-jasmine-matchers',
            'karma-webpack',
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-sourcemap-loader'
        ],

        customLaunchers: {
            IE11: {
                base: 'IE',
                'x-ua-compatible': "IE=EmulateIE11"
            }
        },

        phantomjsLauncher: {
            cmd: {
                win32: path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs.exe')
            }
        }
    });
};
```

My directory structure:

`project
|
└───node_modules 
│
└───src
│    │   jsx files
│    |
│    ├─── __tests__
│    │   │   test files
│    │   │   ...
│    │
└───test
|    │   tests.jsx
│    │
│    │
└───config
|    |
|    |   karma.js`

my tests.jsx

```
const testsContext = require.context("../src", true, /^.*\.(spec|integration-spec)$/);
console.log('found ' + testsContext.keys().length + " tests");
testsContext.keys().forEach(function(k) {
    console.log('executing ' + k + " test");
    console.log(testsContext);
    testsContext(k);
});
module.exports = testsContext;
```

I was able to identify which of them don't get properly required but I cannot figure out why. This is what I get:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.004 secs /
>   0 secs)